# Maintaining muscle with indirect work

Tags: exercise, abdominals, maintenance

Let's says a beginner builds a big chest from horizontal movements and then switches to vertical movements only. *Would the chest atrophy or maintain it's strength and size?*

Or vice versa, if someone does only vertical presses then switches to only horizontal presses, *would the traps maintain or atrophy?*

From my own experience the answer would be yes, because I used to do a lot of abdominal work and after stopping my abdomen has maintained its thickness and definition. And it has been 8 months since the last time I did anything—especially for the abdomen.

*But is this only limited to abdominal muscles?*

Comment: Eight months is not sufficient time for long-developed muscle to atrophy, especially since nearly all athletic movements involve the abs in a stabilizing manner. For instance pull-ups have a strong abdominal component.

Comment: Forearms, calves, and abs get used with a lot of exercises or everyday activities so hard to say. As for muscles .. you'll likely lose a bit of muscle and strength.. if your body doesn't need to have giant chest muscles to push 200 lbs a week every week, your body may try to lose the muscle as it doesn't use the chest muscle.. but with a lot of protein and calorie maintanence or surplus, this is unlikely to be anything significant. Now if you were cutting, your body will try to lose muscle because it's calorie expensive